# Best Dialog windows for ASP.Net Web forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, modal-dialog

What are the best Dialog windows available for ASP.Net Web forms application ? I am using the Modal Dialog right now because at the moment the Web app is focusing only IE. But soon we are going to test for others browsers as well.

It would be great if someone can list out me the best available solution for Dialog windows with proc and cons.

Following is the code that I am using to open up the model dialog in IE.

```
function showDialog(id) {
            var url = "MyPage.aspx?mode=view&nt=C" + "&id=" + id;
            returnValue = myModule.showModalDialog(url);
            if (returnValue) {
                // Call relevant js method 
            }
        }

// My generic modal dialog function 
myModule.showModalDialog = function (url, arguments, features)

{
    if (features == undefined) {
        features = "resizable:yes;status:no;dialogHide:true;help:no;scroll:auto;center:no";
    }
    return window.showModalDialog(url, arguments, features);
}
```

I tried to open up the same modal dialog in non-IE browser (chrome) and dialogs are open up as a different tabs or not opening altogether sometimes. I need to solve this issue with best suitable dialog windows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some framework like Bootstrap which solves many compatibility problems, simplify development and provides you with modal dialogs you need. You can start from here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp